# What is sshkeys-lint

Tags: ssh, keys

I was following some instructions on a website, and it told me to `run sshkeys-lint` to check ssh keys.

I never heard of sshkeys-lint  and can't `apt-get`. Is this a typo?

Comment: Couldn't answer in time, but it looks to be a utility provided with gitolite https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/src/sshkeys-lint

Comment: Can you provide a link to the page so we can tell what it was meant to be doing? As well as the versions of *nix you're running.

Answer (score 3):

Wel the question was closed, now that it is open. The link to the article will be extremely useful, but a quick google search shows sshkeys-lint as a utility provided with gitolite

https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/src/sshkeys-lint

You should be able to install gitolite either by source or via apt-get